# Databricks Community Edition Cluster won't start

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I am trying to start a cluster that was terminated in a Community Edition. However, whenever I click on 'start' the cluster won't start. It would appear I have to create a new cluster everytime I want to work with Databrick clusters. Can someone confirm that is the case?

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This seems to be the case with community edition. You need to create a new cluster every-time and run it. Even in the same session if your cluster stops due to inactivity or some other reason, you will need to create a new cluster.